# Failure to find resource plugin in m2eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, sonarqube

Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Comment: please some one help me to solve above problem?

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Show View -> Maven Repositories. Select *global repositories* -> *central*. Use the context menu to force an update of the index for that repository (it might even start updating automatically, just when you open that view).

Comment: It was not showing any effect by performing the update of the index

Comment: Then you have a simple network problem, as your POM file is available on Maven central: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom. Check your proxy settings in Eclipse and check the Maven settings used by m2eclipse.

Comment: I have all the plugins that required, can i run the project with out connectig to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, means there is any possibility to provide plugins manually to the project to clear the above problem and run successfully.

Comment: @Bananeweizen check for what - having the same problem?

Answer (score -1):

You may try the -U (Update Snapshots) option to force an update during the build.

Comment: Even though by trying the -U option to force an update it was shoeing the same error